# Trying to UPDATE and running into errors

Tags: mysql

Alright, I've been trying to do this all day.  I know this question has been asked and answered before, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around how to make this work.

```
UPDATE 'domain_main.registrarMultiID' =
(
    SELECT r.MultiID#, m.RecId, d.domainId
    FROM domain_main d, Master m, registrar_accounts_multi r
    WHERE d.domainId = m.RecId
    AND r.account = m.Account_CustomerNumber
    AND r.password = m.Password
    AND r.logonName = m.Logon_Username
)
```

What am I missing here?  I understand I'm not supposed to reference domain_main within the select, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem another way.

Comment: I have basically got spreadsheets that are supposed to more or less represent database-based data.  Of course, the spreadsheets don't link nicely the way databases do, so the essence of my question is around building these links through linking tables.  That's why I'm trying to run this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong syntax

```
  UPDATE 'domain_main.registrarMultiID' =
    (
        SELECT r.MultiID#, m.RecId, d.domainId
        FROM domain_main d, Master m, registrar_accounts_multi r
        WHERE d.domainId = m.RecId
        AND r.account = m.Account_CustomerNumber
        AND r.password = m.Password
        AND r.logonName = m.Logon_Username
    )
```

Correct Syntax like below. I am assuming you want to set value of `registrarMultiID` column of `domain_main` table to column value of `MultiID#` belonging to `registrar_accounts_multi` table.

```
UPDATE 'domain_main' As d
INNER JOIN Master as m
   ON d.domainId = m.RecId
INNER JOIN registrar_accounts_multi as r
   ON r.account = m.Account_CustomerNumber
      AND r.password = m.Password
      AND r.logonName = m.Logon_Username
SET d.registrarMultiID = r.MultiID#
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct, this looks good.  I will try it later today.  What was wrong with my syntax?  I also tried UPDATE 'domain_main' SET registrarMultiID = ( SELECT [...] ).